# PHP Valor inesperado al comparar valores flotantes

Tags: php7, float

Ya vi el problema de comparar flotantes con enteros y los decimales.
Aquí se explica en el cuadro rojo:
http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.float.php

Para solucionar esto tenemos la librería: **Matemáticas de precisión arbitraria BCMath**:
http://php.net/manual/es/book.bc.php

Y vendría supuestamente de lujo la función:
*int bccomp ( string $left_operand , string $right_operand [, int $scale = 0 ] )*

Pues bien... ¡¡¡No Funciona!!!! tengo desarrollado un ecommercer que hasta ahora los descuentos eran porcientos de números enteros.

Ahora los descuentos pueden ser:
- Porcentajes enteros
- Porcentajes con decimales
- Cuantía con decimales

Y a la hora de ver en una matriz si hay descuento viene el problema. Probad este código:

```
var_dump(0.61);
var_dump(0.00);
var_dump(bccomp(0.61, 0));
```

Se supone que 0.61 es mayor que 0

Pues la función devuelve esto:

float(0.61) float(0) ***int(0)***

*PHP 7.1.22 me dice que 61 céntimos y nada es lo mismo.*

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
En mi código todo son variales y en las comparaciones siempre fuerzo los valores:

```
if (bccomp((real)$matrizpvp[2], 0.00) !== 0)
if (bccomp((real)$matrizpvp[2], 0) !== 0)
```

He probado de las dos formas, incluso metiendo el cero en una variable.

Comment: Manu para que la pregunta quede más limpia es mejor que los comentarios los añadas como ediciones de la pregunta y no como respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Te falta el tercer parámetro, que indica el número de decimales a usar en la comparación, al no incluirlo sólo compara el valor int.

> bccomp ( string $left_operand , string $right_operand [, int $scale ]
>   )

```
echo bccomp('1.00001', '1', 3); // 0
echo bccomp('1.00001', '1', 5); // 1
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo en este [enlace](http://www.phptutorial.info/?bccomp)

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado momentáneamente con:

```
if ((real)$matrizpvp[2] > 0)
```

Lo cual no me convence, me quedo con muchas dudas y hay muchos puntos en donde se usan estas condiciones.

Answer (score 0):

Madre mía, vaya error de novato, 1000 veces cambié y probé el código y no lo vi, debería ser parámetro obligatorio para que los carajotes como yo no erremos, aquí el ejemplo completo del error:

```
<?php
Echo "<br><b>Mal uso de la función:</b><br>";           

$a= 0.61;
$b= 0.00;

$a = (real)$a;
$b = (real)$b;

echo $a . " (Valor de A)<br>"; 
echo $b . " (Valor de B)<br>"; 
echo bccomp($a, $b) . " (Devolución de bccomp)<br>"; 

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump(bccomp($a, $b));

Echo "<br><b>Buen uso de la función:</b><br>";          

$a= 0.61;
$b= 0.00;

$a = (real)$a;
$b = (real)$b;

echo $a . " (Valor de A)<br>"; 
echo $b . " (Valor de B)<br>"; 
echo bccomp($a, $b, 2) . " (Devolución de bccomp)<br>"; 

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump(bccomp($a, $b, 2));

/*Devuelve:

Mal uso de la función:
0.61 (Valor de A)
0 (Valor de B)
0 (Devolución de bccomp)
float(0.61) float(0) int(0) 

Buen uso de la función:
0.61 (Valor de A)
0 (Valor de B)
1 (Devolución de bccomp)
float(0.61) float(0) int(1)
*/

?>
```